# Join between RDD[(Long, Array[Byte])] and RDD of a case class which has Long field on it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDDs and a case class as follow:

`rdd1:RDD[(Long, Array[Byte])]`

`case class Elem(id: Long, content: Map[Byte, Int])`

and

`rdd2:RDD[Elem]`

How can I join them? how should I indicate that `Elem` has an `id:Long` which should be used for the `join` operation? Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can first transform the 2nd RDD into a PairRDD by converting the case class elements into Tuples via `Elem.unapply`, before the `join` with the 1st RDD:

```
case class Elem(id: Long, content: Map[Byte, Int])

val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (10L, Array[Byte](1, 2, 3)),
  (20L, Array[Byte](4, 5))
))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Elem(10L, Map(1.toByte -> 101, 2.toByte -> 202)),
  Elem(20L, Map(3.toByte -> 303))
))

val joinedRDD = rdd1.join(rdd2.map(Elem.unapply(_).get))
// joinedRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (Array[Byte], Map[Byte,Int]))] = ...

joinedRDD.collect
// res1:  Array[(Long, (Array[Byte], Map[Byte,Int]))] = Array(
//   (10, (Array(1, 2, 3), Map(1 -> 101, 2 -> 202))),
//   (20, (Array(4, 5), Map(3 -> 303)))
// )
```

Comment: I've tried this but I got the message `Type mismatch: Required Elem. Found: Product with Serializable`

Comment: @mjbsgll, I can't reproduce the said error with the example code which runs fine on Spark 2.x. Did it fail when defining `rdd2`, or during the `join`?

Comment: The code didn't compile in `val joinedRDD ...` line. The message is the previous one. I'm using Spark2.2.0 and IntelljIDEA 2019

Comment: I've just tested the example code on a Spark 2.2.1 Shell and it runs fine.  Are you seeing the exact data types of rdd1 and rdd2 `RDD[(Long, Array[Byte])]` and `RDD[Elem]` respectively?  The said error is generally about two different types being mistakenly treated as the same (e.g. treating a Java's collection as Scala's).

Comment: It's weird because I'm seeing the exact data types. The only thing, is Elem is defined into another .scala file where I import it. I'm going to try using spark-shell and also declaring the case class in the same file...